# ng-grid showSelectionCheckbox

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

How to deselect `showSelectionCheckbox` in `ng-grid` if one item gets deselected?

```
$scope.gridData;
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'FullName', displayName: 'Full Name', width: 200, minWidth: 200 },
        { field: 'Roles', displayName: 'Role', width: 200, minWidth: 200 },
        { field: 'Email', displayName: 'Email', width: 225, minWidth: 200 }
        ],
        data: 'gridData',
        //enableColumnResize: true,
        selectWithCheckboxOnly: true,
        showSelectionCheckbox: true,
        checkboxCellTemplate: '<div class="ngSelectionCell" ng-class="Header"><input tabindex="-1" class="ngSelectionCheckbox" class="Header" type="checkbox" ng-checked="row.selected" /></div>',
        selectedItems: []
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>in your gridOptions {} add `multiSelect: false`</strike>

Updated after being shown that I misread the question:

In your gridOptions.afterSelectionChange() function you can grab the first column and set it's visibility to false:

```
$scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.columns[0].visible = false;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @KhanImranAli thank you, I misread the question. I updated my answer to match.